# Register org.bluez.Battery1 in classic bluetooth device

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I want to get battery level of my phone via bluetooth in linux system by bluez api.
in bluez doc is said that there is interface as "org.bluez.Battery1" that has a property as Percentage. So by calling this property we can access the battery level.
In my dbus in org.bluez, there is no interface as "org.bluez.Battery1". a screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ykOy.png) is attached here that represent my dbus in bluez by d-feet tools.

How can I register this?
Is there alternative way to get battery level?